# Unverify the [verify] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

We can safely burninate [verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verify) tag. This tag is being used for lot of unrelated topics ranging from php/java/c# to sql-server/ssh to automation/mockito to...

Total question tagged with [verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verify) - 484

Newest question with [verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verify) tag was almost a year ago - Feb'18

I don't think we need a tag for verifying something - these questions can be covered in other relevant tag. Let's just burninate it.

Comment: One thing I can see the newest question in this tag asked 20 hours ago.

Comment: I think this tag might be a good candidate for burnination, but please go through the [criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/7296893) and list these criteria plus why this tag does or doesn't meet the criterium in your answer. This request seems incomplete to me.

Comment: I don't see why a burn is needed. it doesn't look like it attracts tons of low quality questions.

Comment: @rene when was the necessity of burnination changed? I feel that only useful tags should exist (useful being that it marginally improves the good answers rate) and I fail to see how this one would fulfill that very specific goal.

Comment: @Braiam I don't think it ever was. I agree that only useful tags should exist. I'm not convinced this one is useless.

Comment: `Newest question with verify tag was almost a year ago - Feb'18` Huh? I see 10 minutes ago, one 2 days ago, 8 more in November 2018

Comment: This tag failed [verify]cation. We can, however, [verify] that Trogdor is available to burninate this tag.

Comment: mokito verify is apparently a thing, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889951/how-to-verify-a-method-is-called-two-times-with-mockito-verify

Comment: Yes but Mockito's verify is just a method. Powermock also has a family of them (verifyStatic, verifyAll, verifyPrivate, etc.) There's probably no good reason to have a tag for a method, especially one with a common verb as its name.

Answer (score 13):

To address the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191):

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No, this is wildly ambiguous, and it doesn't even necessarily have anything to do with the actual topic of the question. It's used to indicate everything from the user's end goal (verify something) to names of particular methods in various contexts.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

It's so ambiguous that it's impossible to say.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Only if you think the fact that the method that they're calling happens to be called "verify" helps you understand the question. Unless they're using it to mean something totally different, in which case you don't even have that helpful piece of information. So, no.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, definitely not.

Answer (score -7):

I think we can instead merge this into the [verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verification) tag and mark it as a synonym. This tag seems to be exactly what the [verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verify) tag means, intentionally or not, in a lot of the questions I've seen (I've looked over a hundred or so, didn't read the entirety of the questions).

Meaning of the word verify:

> make sure or demonstrate that (something) is true, accurate,
>   or justified. "his conclusions have been verified by later
>   experiments"

From the [verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verification) tag's info page:

> Verification: "Have we made what we were trying to make?", i.e., does
>   the product conform to the specifications?

My reasoning is that, the word verify, as a tag by itself, doesn't mean much or add much to the question. The word will already be included in the body of the question one way or another. Verification, however, is already a tag that was shaped out and has a tag info and explanations in place.

Of course we'd have to check all 485 questions if we want to be absolutely sure we're not adding anything irrelevant to the verification tag, but I really don't think it's necessary in this particular case.

Comment: Tags should describe what a question is about, not about what the end goal is. These are both equally bad tags that add absolutely nothing to the post, both should be removed.

Comment: @Lundin I think you should add that as an answer here so that people can also vote on that (I was about to do it, but I'm not sure how to phrase it or how to approach that subject.)

Comment: I agree that this would be better than just keeping it how it is now, but it would be better to burninate both of them.